# Is there a way to transparently perform validation on SQLAlchemy objects?

Tags: python, validation, model, dns, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to perform validation on an object after (or as) the properties are set but before the session is committed?

For instance, I have a domain model `Device` that has a `mac` property. I would like to ensure that the `mac` property contains a valid and sanitized mac value before it is added to or updated in the database.

It looks like the Pythonic approach is to do most things as properties (including SQLAlchemy). If I had coded this in PHP or Java, I would probably have opted to create getter/setter methods to protect the data and give me the flexibility to handle this in the domain model itself.

```
public function mac() { return $this->mac; }
public function setMac($mac) {
    return $this->mac = $this->sanitizeAndValidateMac($mac);
}
public function sanitizeAndValidateMac($mac) {
    if ( ! preg_match(self::$VALID_MAC_REGEX) ) {
        throw new InvalidMacException($mac);
    }
    return strtolower($mac);
}
```

What is a Pythonic way to handle this type of situation using SQLAlchemy?

(While I'm aware that validation and should be handled elsewhere (i.e., web framework) I would like to figure out how to handle some of these domain specific validation rules as they are bound to come up frequently.)

**UPDATE**

I know that I could use [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) to do this under normal circumstances. The key part is that I am using SQLAlchemy with these classes. I do not understand exactly how SQLAlchemy is performing its magic but I suspect that creating and overriding these properties on my own could lead to unstable and/or unpredictable results.

Answer (score 16):

You can add data validation inside your SQLAlchemy classes using the `@validates()` decorator.

From the docs - [Simple Validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#simple-validators):

> An attribute validator can raise an exception, halting the process of mutating the attribute’s value, or can change the given value into something different.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class EmailAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)

    @validates('email')
    def validate_email(self, key, address):
        # you can use assertions, such as
        # assert '@' in address
        # or raise an exception:
        if '@' not in address:
            raise ValueError('Email address must contain an @ sign.')
        return address
```

Comment: Just a quick question: if I want simple "presence" validation, should I just add `nullable=false` to the column declaration and then try to catch the `session.commit()` errors? Or should I try a similar validator? Thanks.

Comment: @art-solopov the simple validator is pretty simple to use, and the decorator arguments takes a tuple, so if you have other fields that need the same validation just add it to the args tuple.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. This can be done nicely using a MapperExtension.

```
# uses sqlalchemy hooks to data model class specific validators before update and insert
class ValidationExtension( sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension ):
    def before_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        """not every instance here is actually updated to the db, see http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/interfaces.html?highlight=mapperextension#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension.before_update"""
        instance.validate()
        return sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension.before_update(self, mapper, connection, instance)
    def before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        instance.validate()
        return sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension.before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance)


sqlalchemy.orm.mapper( model, table, extension = ValidationExtension(), **mapper_args )
```

You may want to check [before_update](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/interfaces.html?highlight=mapperextension#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension.before_update) reference because not every instance here is actually updated to the db.

Comment: `MapperExtension` was removed from SQLAlchemy in [v1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-6daf2f59ac2438ef9c8213e9ebeac157). Use [mapper events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html#mapper-events) instead.

Answer (score 2):

"It looks like the Pythonic approach is to do most things as properties"

It varies, but that's close.

"If I had coded this in PHP or Java, I would probably have opted to create getter/setter methods..."

Good.  That's Pythonic enough.  Your getter and setter functions are bound up in a property; that's pretty good.

What's the question?

Are you asking how to spell [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)?

However, "transparent validation" -- if I read your example code correctly -- may not really be all that good an idea.

Your model and your validation should probably be kept separate.  It's common to have multiple validations for a single model.  For some users, fields are optional, fixed or not used; this leads to multiple validations.

You'll be happier following the Django design pattern of using a [Form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) for validation, separate form the model.

Comment: I am not sure what sort of magic SQLAlchemy uses to bind to the Model class properties. I would not assume it is safe to define my own `mac = property()` on my class. I think my question is is this safe to do? If so, are there any gotchas? If not, what are some other alternatives?

Comment: There is no magic.  That are no gotchas.  The alternative is what we generally do:  we do validation *outside* the model class, making it even simpler.  Define your validation *outside* the model, and then you don't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: I don't know how often you will get different validations for the same model, that would generally drive the DBA crazy (the ORM model's constraints should be driven by the actual data model's constraint, or you're defeating the purpose of the ORM pattern). If you have separate use cases, then make your model polymorphic. Tight coupling is the better answer here, especially since you have introspection (in 2017: `inspect` module) to dynamically refer to the validation from the schema metadata itself).