# SQLAlchemy accepts everything like different data types, empty strings, strings with bigger length

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-testing

I am using Flask and Flask SQLAlchemy and Flask Test. I define an example model with a string column with max length of 100. I thought I should get an exception if I try to insert a string with a length bigger than 100. SQLAlchemy even allows me to insert other data types like an int. Even if I have defined this column to be of type string. Or if I try to insert an empty string I also do not raise an Exception. Although I have set the column not to be nullable.

Why does SQLAlchemy just accepts everything. Shouldn't there be at least one exception raised?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_testing import TestCase


db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(self):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite://"

    db.init_app(app)

    return app


class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)


class MyTest(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        return create_app(self)

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def test_example_that_should_work(self):
        example = Example(name="ABC")

        db.session.add(example)
        db.session.commit()

        self.assertEqual(Example.query.count(), 1)

    def test_example__do_not_insert_strings_of_bigger_size(self):
        example = Example(name="ABC"*100)

        db.session.add(example)
        db.session.commit()

        self.assertEqual(Example.query.count(), 0)  # AssertionError: 1 != 0

    def test_example_do_not_insert_different_data_type(self):
        example = Example(name=42)

        db.session.add(example)
        db.session.commit()

        self.assertEqual(Example.query.count(), 0)  # AssertionError: 1 != 0

    def test_example_do_not_insert_nullable(self):
        example = Example(name="")

        db.session.add(example)
        db.session.commit()

        self.assertEqual(Example.query.count(), 0)  # AssertionError: 1 != 0
```

Comment: No, because the underlying database is sqlite and it will accept pretty much anything

Comment: Is there a way that I can define that SQLAlchemy checks the data type before adding to the database. Because I like testing with sqlite.

Comment: I'm trying to dig out the comment I want from the docs that's basically "SQLite ultimately doesn't care about datatypes on inserts". As for SQLAlchemy, I can't say. But it's not boundless on SQLite so I'd like to find the definitive comments.

Comment: I'm not able to find the comment I want right now, but the [intro of this](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) says that the types are dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I then use PostgresSQL for testing.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980982/5320906).