# Accepting multiple types on an SQLAlchemy model field

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Consider an SQLAlchemy model with a `String` field:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    name = Column(String(100))
    # ...
```

What is the right way to have this field accept e.g. `int` values and convert them to strings before saving and querying - essentially `str(val)` ?

Eventually I want all of these to be equivalent:

```
m = MyModel(name='123')
m = MyModel(name=123)
q = session.query(MyModel).filter_by(name='123')
q = session.query(MyModel).filter_by(name=123)
```

Comment: Have you read this section in the docs? [Use Descriptors and Hybrids](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#using-descriptors-and-hybrids).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested on MySQL and your original code works as is:

```
class MyModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'mymodel'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column("name", String(100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    s = Session()
    new_obj = MyModel(name=123)
    print(type(new_obj.name))  # <class 'int'>
    s.add(new_obj)
    s.commit()
    s.close()

    s = Session()
    obj = s.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.name == 123).one()  # query with integer value
    print(obj.name, type(obj.name))  # 123 <class 'str'>
```

In [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980982/6560549), relating to validation and coercion of data types @zzzeek says that sqlalchemy:

> ...defers to the DBAPI/database as the best and most efficient source
>   of validation and coercion of values.

That answer also details one way you could use the SQLAlchemy [Event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html) system to intercept data as it's set on instrumented attributes and do stuff.

Another way would be to use a `hybrid_property` decorator and an associated `setter` to do stuff to attribute values as they are set. It handles both creating new objects and querying:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class MyModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'mymodel'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name_ = Column("name", String(100))

    @hybrid_property
    def name(self):
        return self.name_

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        self.name_ = str(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    s = Session()
    new_obj = MyModel(name=123)
    print(type(new_obj.name))  # <class 'str'>
    s.add(new_obj)
    s.commit()
    s.close()

    s = Session()
    obj = s.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.name == 123).one()  # query with integer value
    print(obj.name, type(obj.name))  # 123 <class 'str'>
```

All of those methods are well documented and so could be considered 'right'.